# Would a neon sign change color if it started moving away from the observer?

Tags: visible-light

Simple question dealing with doppler efect for light-waves.

If we had a huge neon sign in the sky and if it suddenly gained large velocity away from Earth, would it change color (for human eye) towards the red part of the spectrum? Possibly become invisible?

Comment: Yes, of course. Why do you ask?

Comment: Just something I was wondering about. I want give a non-physics person an example that visualises the shifted absorption lines of distant galaxies.

Comment: If you like astronomy, a useful search term is “spectroscopic binary.” Neon in particular doesn’t contribute very much to the spectra of stars, but the idea is absolutely the same. The extent to which the change would be *visible* gets into the biology and neurology of human color perception, which some users feel is off-topic for our community.

Comment: Thanks a lot <3